# can't access to my css file in my jsp

Tags: css, jsp, spring-mvc

i have some issue accessing my CSS file. I did search, but i can't figure out what's incorrect.

web.xml :

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.mvc</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

my JSP :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Portail web </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="../GN/css/portail.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>TEST</h1>
</body>
<html>
```

my css :

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
body
{
background-color:blue;
}
```

My architecture :

JSP is at : `webapp/WEB-INF/FR/JSP/portail.jsp`

CSS is at : `webapp/WEB-INF/GN/css/portail.css`

I tried absolute path too, but nothing work (no style applied on my JSP).

Thanks.

EDIT :

If i do `<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/GN/css/portail.css"%>` it prints out my css, so the path is good but the style does not apply to my jsp :/

Answer (score 3):

It's the web browser that is requesting the files from the web server. Your pages aren't directly accessing the files at all. All the files inside `WEB-INF/` **are not** publicly accessible.

You have two possible solutions:

1. Move .js and .CSS files outside of WEB-INF/
2. Or use the following mapping:

   **web.xml** (Spring 3.0.3+)

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>debug</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>listings</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In JSP use path `/static/js/`, `/static/css/` etc.

Comment: /WEB-INF/GN/css/portail.css is the correct absolute path. but my path is correct i'm sure, it prints out my css file if i do <%include%>..

Comment: "All the files inside WEB-INF/ are not publicly accessible" and "Move .js and .CSS files outside of WEB-INF/" is pretty much the solution!!

Answer (score 0):

`../GN/css/portail.css` point to `FR/GN/css/portail.css` and not to `GN/css/portail.css`

Try with `../../GN/css/portail.css`

(If you are accessing your jsp directly but maybe is it forwarded from an action with a different url)

Comment: yes sorry, it was for testing, it was ../../GN but it's not working neither. i accessing my jsp with my controller which @RequestMapping("/portail.mvc") ?

Comment: Have you tried with `GN/css/portail.css`? If your mapping path is at the root of your webapp